# How to add custom headers to nx react app?

Tags: reactjs, header, nomachine-nx

I need add to my react app

```
'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp',
'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
```

How i can do it? I'm use monorep with nx.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to your webapp and how you handle request inside it.
If you use a global http client instance. Just assign this header globally in your app.